# How to rebuild the Visual Studio Toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, controls, toolbox

The toolbox in Visual Studio Professional 2008 has somehow ended up with 12 instances of each control.  They are just the standard controls, no third party controls, and I have no third party plugins.

Is there a way to rebuild the toolbox to correct this issue with the dupes?  I've been living with it for a while, but it's pretty annoying.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Did you try right clicking the Toolbox and selecting "Reset Toolbox"?

That should reset it to the defaults.

Comment: This worked for Visual Studio 2010 adding the surface controls 4 times too.

Answer (score 24):

You can also go into the folder "C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0" and delete the *.tbd files.  I have had to do this a couple times to get rid of duplicate items and when Reset Toolbox crashes without warning.

Comment: In my case, Visual Studio crashed while using the Forms Editor or performing "Reset Toolbox", but your solution worked well, thanks.

Comment: See [Jonx answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4329415/199364) for more recent versions of Windows.

Answer (score 13):

"Reset Toolbox" didn't work out for me.

Deleting the *.tbd in the following dir on Windows 7x64 worked for me...
C:\Users[Current user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

Comment: I had VS crashing every time I accessed the Toolbox window. Deleting the .tbd files fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Actually I just figured it out.  You can right click on the Toolbox and click "Reset Toolbox."  this fixed my issue.  I'll leave this here in case anyone else has the same problem in the future.

Comment: Sometimes "Reset Toolbox" does not work and generates an operating system error, so you have to delete the .tbd files.

Answer (score 3):

Reset toolbox also helped for me to reset DevExpress duplicate controls.

Comment: FWIW, I had the *opposite* experience when using the competing *DevComponents DotNetBar*: Every time I Reset Toolbox, it added *another duplicate*!  Had to delete the *.tbds to get rid of them.