# Visual Studio 2013 Express Toolbox empty

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to learn Visual Basic with the guidance of some YouTube Tutorials. They have recommended the use of Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 as it has a built in compiler. I encountered a problem where my toolbox bar on the left of my screen is empty. Does anyone know how to fix this?
http://gyazo.com/328ade3754613c971dd6d4745a0ed171 This is a link to my screenshot.

Answer (score 23):

Just right click inside tools and click on "show all"

Answer (score 3):

Your code may be running. Make sure to stop all processes and view the toolbox again.

Answer (score 2):

On Visual Studio C++ 2012, it also happen sometimes. Try, to right click inside the Toolbox dialog and click on "Reset Toolbox" item. It should solve your problem.

See same question: [How to rebuild the Visual Studio Toolbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268298/how-to-rebuild-the-visual-studio-toolbox)

Comment: Sorry that it doesn't work. Perhaps, you could try to reset your VS settings ("devenv /ResetSettings"). See this post: http://ruchirac.blogspot.fr/2012/06/reset-visual-studio-user-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to **open your code in [Design] view**. In this view you don't see the code as text, but rather as windows and buttons and so on.

Choose your favorite way to switch to the [Design] view :

```
A. View > Designer
B. Shift + F7
C. In the Solution Explorer window double click Form1.cs
```

Source:
[How do I open a Visual Studio project in design view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137556/how-do-i-open-a-visual-studio-project-in-design-view)