# Any alternative to 'Choose items' in VS toolbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, custom-controls, windows-8.1, toolbox

I'd like to add a custom control to my VS toolbox but the VS crash when I click on toolbox -> mouse right-click -> 'choose items...'. I read it's a know VS bug (since VS 08, from what I've read) that wasn't fixed yet.

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

1. start in safe mode: `WDExpress /safemode`
2. run as adm
3. Reset the Toolbox.
4. Check for the `.tbd` files and then delete them. But actually there are no any `.tbd` files in those folders:

> C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0
>
> C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0

(I guess there are two folder because I have the VS WEB installed apart from the VS 13, which I'm using and haveing that issue)

5. [All those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268298/how-to-rebuild-the-visual-studio-toolbox) answers.
6. Try to clear [this registers](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18560), which didn't exits in my installation.

NOTE: I didn't have any thrid party libraries installed. This is the very first one I will install.

But it didn't made any difference on my case and still crash. Any workaround? maybe add it via command-line or something? I'm pretty sure reinstall it will not make difference either.

**EDIT**: I didn't find the `devenv.exe` (to run `/safemode` flag) in my VS installation folder but I read `WDExpress` is the equivalent to so I ran it.

**EDIT 2:** This is the screenshot before the crash:

[image]

**EDIT 3**: [Here's](http://pastebin.com/3uVbMcPF) some information from the Event Viewer of my system.
Not sure if it helps. My giess is: it did crashed when trying to get the version of the `microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.dll` dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours I finally I fixed it :) I hope it useful to anyone. This was pretty simple: control panel -> Add or Remove Programs -> select the Visual Studio -> Add or Remove -> will open the VS uninstall program, click on Repair button. After repair finishied I restarted the machine and worked fine for me.